# How to make a query with the data of another query on SQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a user table and another order table. A user can have many orders. How do I get the last 1000 users and those users use my last 1000 orders for each one?

Query - Get users

```
select distinct users.id, users.first_name, users.last_name
from users
limit 2;
```

Query - Get orders

```
select distinct orders.id, orders.user_id
from orders
limit 2;
```

Comment: MySQL <> PostgreSQL. Please specify which RDBMS are you using ?

Comment: Sorry, I am using  PostgreSQL

Comment: to know the "last" you will need to know when the users made the order. namely, add something like "purchase_date"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to know.. When it comes to query data don't do separate operation.. If you put out All `Users` and `Orders` Your data will be `unordered` and not consistency.. So you need to make `Join` to see All `User` with `Order` they have.. And as stated by @Sharon you need to add column `date_ordered` to see that `order` make.. I am assume you already have that column but i will call that column with `date_ordered`..

And your query will be :

```
select
  users.id, 
  users.first_name, 
  users.last_name,
  orders.id
from
  users
  inner join orders on users.id = orders.user_id
order by
  orders.date_ordered desc
limit 1000
```

By order `date_ordered` use `desc` you will get the latest all the user with their order.. And i assume `user_id` column in table `orders` have constraint `foreign key` references to table `users` with column `id`..